# I want to compare a 2d numpy array to find that data is lies between the range or not if yes than it should be append in new group

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, valueerror

I want to compare 2d numpy array with the single x_min , x_max and same for the value of y but I didn't understand the concept of loop in this case how to define loop to compare and use numpy.where_logical_and.

```py
import numpy as np

group_count = 0
xy = np.array([[116,2306],[118,2307],[126,1517]])
idx = np.array([[0,0],[0,1]])
group1 = []

for l in xy:
    for i in idx:
        for j in range(1):
            x_temp = xy[idx[i][j]]
            x1 = x_temp[0][0]
            y1 = x_temp[0][1]
            x1_max = x1 + 60
            x1_min = x1 - 60
            y1_max = y1 +60
            y1_min = y1 - 60
            range_grp_1 = [x1_max,x1_min,y1_min,y1_max]
            grp1 = [x1,y1]
            grp_1 = np.array(grp1)
            #print(grp_1,range_grp_1)
            if group_count != 0:
                print('group count greater than 0')
                if np.where((l[i]>x1_min) and (l[i]<x1_max) and (l[i]>y1_min) and (l[i]<y1_max)):
                    print(l[i])

            else:
                group1.append(grp_1)
                group_count+=1
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: don't you want  `if x1_min < l[i][0] < x1_max and y1_min < l[i][1] < y1_max : print(l[i])` ?

Comment: well I want to make a group of data which lies in the range between x min max and y min max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post a new code here.

As you said you have a lot of points and the ranges seems to variate, I propose you to wrap the control inside a function, so you can call it as many times as you need to, passing the range of coordinates to be evaluated.

```
# function to return max and min of list of coordinates
def  min_max(coords):   

   xy = np.array(coords)

   xs = [] #save 'x' values
   for i in range(len(xy)):
        x = [xy[i][0]]
        xs.append(x)   

   ys = [] #save 'y' values
   for i in range(len(xy)):
        y = [xy[i][1]]
        ys.append(y)

   rangex    = []
   rangey    = []

   for x in min(xs): #get min 'x'
       minx = x - 60
       rangex.append(minx)
       maxx = x + 60
       rangex.append(maxx)

   for y in min(ys):  #get min 'y'
        miny = y - 60
        rangey.append(miny)
        maxy = y + 60      
        rangey.append(maxy)

   return [rangex,rangey]
```

If you pass the same coordinates you posted the first time, it returns

```
    Execution #1:
    coords = [[116,2306],[118,2307],[126,1517]]
    my_ranges = min_max(coords)
    print(my_ranges)
    #[[56, 176], [1457, 1577]]
```

Or if you pass just the new range you gave me:

```
   Execution #2:
   new_coord = [[518,2007]]#pay attention to the format
   my_ranges = min_max(new_coord)
   print(my_ranges)
   #[[458, 578], [1947, 2067]]
```

And the last part of the code. The one that separates the groups if they belongs to the evaluated range or not.

```
   #changed again:
   group1 = [] #coords in the interval
   group2 = [] #coords out of the interval

   for l in dynCoords:
        pair = [l[0],l[1]]  
        if l[0] in range(my_ranges[0][0],my_ranges[0][1]) and l[1] in range(my_ranges[1][0],my_ranges[1][1]):
                 group1.append(pair)
        else:
                 group2.append(pair)

   #new line appended
   my_ranges = min_max(group2)
```

With the original coordinates [[116,2306],[118,2307],[126,1517]] the groups [118,2307],[126,1517] got out of the range, and went to group2. With the new line appended they were used to change the minimun threshold again, now it goes from 56-2246 for xs and 176-2366 for ys. Let's say you use group2 in dynCoords, dynCoords = group2 and execute what goes under the label #changed again, you get for group1: [[116, 2306], [118, 2307]] and group2 goes empty.

I think you can make a function for that part of the code too. And run it as many times as you need to treat all your coordinates set.

Comment: I don't want to get min and max from x and min and max from y. I just want that if the data lies in the range than it append to the new group. For example, if I have first element [116 2306] then I deduct 60 and add in both coordinates to find a min or max after that I want compare all other coordinates which lies in that range then they append in group array otherwise create new array

Comment: Could you provide us an example of the expected output?

Comment: we have coordinates which were mentioned in the code. Then I want to extract 1st element by using for loop which was [116 2306] and then I add 60 and deduct from the coordinates which was called minx miny max x max y(56 2246 176 2366) and I want that if the array find in that rand like x in (56-176) and y in (2246-2366) then I want to append in new array or list whatever suits.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get you. I've updated the code considering the 60s and added further questions.

Comment: see last answer

Comment: Thank you for being patient. I think I've got it now. The code was edited.

Comment: your update code absolutely works and I appreciate your work. Thank You so much. :)

Comment: Of courser. What do you need? Post here or open a new question. I just don't know if I can help you today, going out of the town in a few hours for the holiday. I'll be available for sure tomorrow.

Comment: ohk sure. I posted a new answer you can refer it.

Comment: I think I saw a post of your new answer this afternoon at my cell phone, something about group2. I don't find it anymore. Have you changed your mind?

Comment: No it was deleted. I put new question by sometime

Comment: I want to make above thing is dynamic for eg. which points are lies in range we append in the group1 but now I want to do same for the remaining points. Suppose we have [518 2007] then I want to take this and find min max of it and applied same concept as applied for [116 2307] and that will be append in the next group two. As I have lot of points that's why I want to make it dynamic. This is the complex thing and I want to built it.

Comment: Check it out. I changed everything to accomplish what you asked for. I hope it helps.

Comment: you do correct and I appreciate your work it is very helpful for me but I still stick at point if we have coordinates [1008,256] then again it has never in any range so we have to make dynamic group which store all remaining data consistently. Well If you understand this is good. If not just leave it because its most complex problem to solve it. Can you give me your email id?

Comment: Changed again. I think it absolutely handles the situation you describe.

Answer (score 0):

you going to correct. 
Suppose we have 1st element of the array: [116 1517]

```
x_min = 116-60  (56)
x_max = 116+60  (176)
y_min = 1517-60 (1457)
y_max = 1517+60 (1577)
```

now the other coordinates compare to these values:
for example :
now we have array = [146 1568]
then

```
x =146 y=1568
if x>x_min and x<x_max and y<y_max and y>y_max
       grp.append(array)
else:
       print('not in range)
```

so I want this type of output

```
146>56 and 146<176 and 1568>1457 and 1568<1577
```

this might be true so it would append in new array